# Video Host Broken link check

Tags: php, curl, hyperlink

I have Nowvideo and some other video host video links. How can i check that video deleted or not?

```
 http://www.nowvideo.co/video/cd2950fb2561c //Working link
 http://www.nowvideo.sx/video/72de6ef0d8519  // Not work
```

And My code

```
function check_url($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$headers = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $headers['http_code'];
}

$url = "http://www.nowvideo.sx/video/72de6ef0d8519";

$check_url_status = check_url($url);
if ($check_url_status == '200')
echo "Link Works";
else
  echo "Broken Link";
 ?>
```

this return "Link Works". But this link video is deleted. But domain working 
How can i find that Link video deleted or not?

Comment: The page is still returning a working response, the content of the page is changed based on if the video is deleted or not. You need to check the content not just the status code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now Video has an API you can use to check this. According to [the documentation](http://www.nowvideo.sx/api-doc.php?q=alive) though, there is no check to see if something was previously available and has since been deleted, only a check to see if it is currently available.

So you can use the link

```
http://www.nowvideo.sx/api-v2/alive.php?link=http://www.nowvideo.sx/video/[yourVideoId]
```

To get a json response as to whether the video exists:

```
{"resultCode":"200","message":"OK","result":1,"data":null}
```

or (and I'm guessing because it's not specified in the docs)

```
{"resultCode":"404","message":"NOT_FOUND","result":0,"data":null}
```

Comment: Note, this is only for Now Video. Other service will provide their own APIs for checking this kind of thing.

Comment: much better than the other answers on here which work by coincidence rather than by design.

Comment: There is any other way?

Comment: What do you mean? Doesn't this do what you want?

Comment: Every video provider will do things a little bit different. The problems with not using the API is you'll end up **page scrapping** (reading content from the page). This is easy (though will still require different implementations for different services), and might work for a while, but eventually sites move on and change their content and your scrape won't work any more. **API**'s (theoretically) should never change, so you can always rely on them. Not sure what other providers your using but all the providers I use (YouTube, Vimeo, etc) provide APIs.

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot use HTTP headers for determining whether the page contains a video or not. What you could do, is to search the HTML page for the error message (or use an API, which might also be available). Try this:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$novideo = "This file no longer exists on our servers."
if(strpos($data, $novideo) === FALSE) {
    echo "Link Works";
}
else {
    echo "Broken Link";
}
```

Comment: One problem with this is it's dependent on them never changing the content of the page. If they do, this will break.